# Error al mostrar imagen en consulta PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy intentando ejecutar este código **mostrarImagen.php** para mostrar una imagen almacenada en una carpeta que tiene esta ruta: `C:\xampp\htdocs\upload`

El archivo mostrado se encuentra en esta ruta: `C:\xampp\htdocs\login_crud\mostrarImagen.php`

Al ejecutar este **mostrarImagen.php** me muestra el siguiente error:

```php
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "<" in C:\xampp\htdocs\login_crud\leerImagenes.php on line 32
```

Código:

```php
<?php 
include_once 'dashboard/bd/conexion_ventasLog.php';
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();

$consulta = "SELECT foto FROM ventas_log WHERE id=1";
$resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
$resultado->execute();
$data=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($data);//esto no muestra nada

while ($fila=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $ruta_img="$fila['foto'];
}
echo $ruta_img; //esto no muestra nada
?>
<div>
    <img src="/upload/<?php echo $ruta_img;?>" alt="Imagen"/>
</div>
```

He intentado cambiar esta línea de diferentes maneras para encontrar el error como esta:

```html
<img src="../upload/<?php echo $ruta_img;?>" alt="Imagen"/>
```

pero aún persiste el error ¿Está mal construida esta línea o dependería de la consulta creada anteriormente? Digo esto último porque la verdad es que el `echo $ruta_img;` no está mostrando nada al ponerlo aisladamente.

Nota:La bd **ventas_log** contiene varios atributos uno de los cuales es **"foto"** que contiene el nombre del archivo foto (ej:pajaro.jpg) para hacer referencia a dicho archivo al construir la ruta `<img src="/upload/<?php echo $ruta_img;?>"" alt="Imagen"/>`

Comment: Mira de sustituir esto `$ruta_img="$fila(foto);` por esto: `$ruta_img=$fila[foto];` y dime si eso lo arregla

Comment: Antes de la etiqueta `<div>` tienes que poner la etiqueta de cierre php...

Comment: Si esta línea no muestra nada: `var_dump($data);` quiere decir que no está trayendo nada de la BD. Ejecuta directamente esa consulta desde la BD a ver si te trae resultados. Y debido a que le hiciste un `fetchAll` a `$result`, no va a entrar al `while` porque el objeto ya fue recorrido en su totalidad.

Comment: Aquí tienes un doble comilla demás ```"``` ```<img src="/upload/<?php echo $ruta_img;?>""^^ alt="Imagen"/>``` y aparte  ```$ruta_img``` al no imprimir nada cambia ```$ruta_img="$fila(foto);```, por ```$ruta_img=$fila['foto'];```

Comment: Jolin, quien da mas? :-)

Comment: ¿Es que solo yo veo que falta la etiqueta de cierre php y que es por eso que da error al encontrar el primer `<` del `div`?

Comment: eh eh, que yo solo lo he mirado en diagonal y he visto eso del `"$fila(foto)` sin pensar que podia haber algo más... lo llego a saber y me callo... hay que reescribir demasiadas cosas, je... pensaba que era un typo, pero son demasiados... alguien deberia redactarle una respuesta completa (yo no puedo ahora)

Comment: Hay bastantes pequeños errores. Pero empezaría por tu ```var_dump($data);```, si este no trae nada, tampoco vas a obtener tu imagen. Fíjate que tu *id* no sea un entero, ya que lo pasas como cadena: ```WHERE id='1'``` prueba poner ```WHERE id=1```, aunque lo correcto si usas *sentencias preparadas* sería algo como ```WHERE id=?``` y una vez obtienes esos datos, sigues con el resto de codigo.

Comment: Ok gracias por todos los comentarios. He cambiado el codigo siquiendo sus indicaciones y han mejorado varias cosas (edité el código). Ahora el var_dump($data) muestra esto:
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["foto"]=> string(10) "pajaro.jpg" } } 
En cambio, el "echo $ruta_img;" muestra lo siguiente:
Warning: Undefined variable $ruta_img in C:\xampp\htdocs\login_crud\leerImagenes.php on line 30
Eso quiere decir que la consulta está mal realizada o le falta algo que no entiendo ya que se está haciendo referencia a $fila['foto'] que es parte del array que ahora si se esta mostrando como resultado.

Comment: Sigues dejando unas comillas de más  `"` dentro de la asignación de `$ruta_img="$fila[foto];`... debe ser así: `$ruta_img=$fila[foto];` tal como dije en mi primer comentario

Answer (score 2):

En tu código hay bastantes errores de sintaxis. Y se te ve dando tumbos en la forma de leer tus datos. Por otra parte, estás programando ingenuamente, a lo que yo llamo *programación optimista*. O sea, un tipo de programación donde uno piensa que *todo irá bien*. Pues no, no siempre va todo bien y tu tarea como programador es **ser pesimista**, es decir, pensar que todo puede salir mal, y que uno de tus propósitos es que el código sepa qué hacer cuando algo salga mal.

Corrigiendo todo lo dicho, podríamos escribir tu código de este modo, he puesto comentarios en los puntos importantes, para que se entienda:

```
<?php 
  include_once 'dashboard/bd/conexion_ventasLog.php';
  $objeto = new Conexion();
  /*
    Verificamos si hay conexión a la 
    base de datos 
    */
  if ($conexion = $objeto->Conectar()) {
    /*
      Usaremos consultas preparadas, pues
      supongo que el id lo quieres pasar de forma dinámica
      */
    $id=1;
    $consulta = "SELECT foto FROM ventas_log WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1";

    /*
      Verificamos que no hay error preparando 
      */
    if ($resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta)) {
      /*
        Parámetros para evitar inyección SQL 
        en el caso de que $id venga de una fuente externa 
        */
      $params=array(":id"=>$id);

      /*
        Pasamos los parámetros en el execute, para que 
        el controlador verifique posibles inyecciones de código 
        */
      $resultado->execute($params);
      /*
        Dado que esperas una sola fila / columna 
        bastaria con usar fetchColumn() en este caso
        Lee cuando puedas los diferentes tipos de fetch 
        y usa siempre el más adecuado 
        */
      $ruta_img=$resultado->fetchColumn();  
      /*
        Concatenamos limpiamente en una variable 
        sin confusas mezclas de bloques PHP / HTML 
        */
      $html="<div>
                <img src=\"/upload/$ruta_img alt=\"Imagen\"/>
            </div>";
    } else {
      /* 
        Salida para posible error preparando 
        */
      $html="<p>Error preparando la consulta</p>";
    }  
    /*
      Salida para posible error en la conexión a la BD 
      */
  } else {
    $html="<p>Error no hay conexión</p>";
  }
  /*
    Imprimimos lo que haya ocurrido 
    Si aún así no ves nada en pantalla 
    pon un var_dump($html); para depurar
    */
  echo $html;
```

Comment: Gracias a todos. Ver mis errores me ayuda mucho para comprender y seguir aprendiendo.